# Hello i am trying to run my django app in pythonanywhere and i get this error .does by any chance anyone experienced something similar isues?

Tags: python, django, server

error log

```
2020-04-07 09:50:50,115: ***************************************************
2020-04-07 09:50:50,115: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-04-07 09:50:50,115: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2020-04-07 09:50:50,115: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-04-07 09:50:50,115: ***************************************************
2020-04-07 09:50:53,872: Error running WSGI application
2020-04-07 09:50:53,873: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psych_test_demo'
2020-04-07 09:50:53,873:   File "/var/www/evaldasmencinskas_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2020-04-07 09:50:53,873:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-04-07 09:50:53,873: 
2020-04-07 09:50:53,874:   File "/home/evaldasmencinskas/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-04-07 09:50:53,874:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-04-07 09:50:53,874: 
2020-04-07 09:50:53,874:   File "/home/evaldasmencinskas/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-04-07 09:50:53,874:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-04-07 09:50:53,874: 
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875:   File "/home/evaldasmencinskas/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875:     self._setup(name)
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875: 
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875:   File "/home/evaldasmencinskas/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875: 
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875:   File "/home/evaldasmencinskas/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875: ***************************************************
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-04-07 09:50:53,875: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2020-04-07 09:50:53,876: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-04-07 09:50:53,876: ***************************************************
```

i tried using diferent names for virtualenv like mysite-virtualenv and psych_test_demo-master
i got installed everything required for app to work like django and xlsxwriter 
this is how my wsgi.py file looks like.i got python 3.8 here.

```
import os
import sys

# assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/myusername/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
path = '/home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master/psych_test_demo'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'psych_test_demo.settings'


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

this is first time for me trying to run app on a server so i might do really dumb mistakes so everything is possible.thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `wsgi.py` file, your path `variable` should be same as that of the `BASE_DIR` (outer project directory).

```
path =   "/home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master"  # ( Path to your outer project directory )
```

Comment: '/home/myusername/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
path = '/home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master'

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'psych_test_demo-master.settings'                                                                                                  this doesn't work

Comment: this is the one with settings.py file ,/home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master/psych_test_demo and this one with manage.py file  /home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master .it the description it said to use the one with setings.py inside.

Comment: i did ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['evaldasmencinskas.pythonanywhere.com'] still geting same error

Comment: Did you Reload your web app in pythonanywhere web app setup?

Comment: yes many times. still same  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psych_test_demo' i think it got something to do with the names.

Comment: Did you specified the Working directory in pythonanywhere web app setup?

Comment: source code directory i made this /home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master

Comment: virtual env directory /home/evaldasmencinskas/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv

Comment: when i run   python -i /var/www/www_my_domain_com_wsgi.py   i get   python: can't open file '/var/www/www_my_domain_com_wsgi.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: i got 4 files in that var/www/ directory 
 evaldasmencinskas_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py   evaldasmencinskas_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py.2020-04-01-16-26.bak

 evaldasmencinskas_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py.2020-04-04-14-00.bak

 evaldasmencinskas_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py.2020-04-06-16-05.bak

Comment: can this be my problem?  # add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/evaldasmencinskas/emotion test/Emotion/mytest'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_home)

Comment: same error .no its still path = '/home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master/psych_test_demo'

Comment: @Snip3rmeow path="/home/evaldasmencinskas/psych_test_demo-master"

Comment: yeah i just made it into that and it worked thank .you saved my life :D